# fabric js image filters makes image of bad quality

Tags: canvas, fabricjs, imagefilter

I am using fabric JS and tried to use image filters on image object

Here is my code

```
function drawImage(ele) {
            var img = new fabric.Image(ele, {
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
                top: getRandomNum(0, canvasHeight - 100),
                left: getRandomNum(0, canvasWidth - 100)
            });            
            canvas.add(img);
            canvas.isDrawingMode = false;
        }
```

above function adds an image to the canvas.

And here is the function that makes selected image object gray.

```
var isGray = false;
        function makeImageGray() {
            isGray = !isGray;
            var img = canvas.getActiveObject();
            if (img != null && img.type == "image") {
                applyFilter(0, isGray && new fabric.Image.filters.Grayscale())
            }
            else {
                alert("Please select single image on canvas");
            }
            canvas.isDrawingMode = false;
        }
```

when above function is called it makes image blurry and dull quality

Comment: Same issue here. I found that when the image is added by `fabric.Image()` rather than with `fabric.Image.fromURL()` this issue happens. 
I still don't know how to fix it except to use the second function to add my image.